# Apply background-image for dropdown is not working on IE

Tags: javascript, css

Applied Background image for a Drop-down it works fine in FF and other modern browser but not in IE(all version)

here is my code:
`div.timeslots select {
        background: url("./images/imag1e.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -48px transparent;
        border: 0 none;
        color: #999999;
        font-size: 12px;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 6px;
        width: 242px;
}`

can anyone help me to fix this issues

Answer (score 0):

There is no fix. It is not supported.